# Error with compiling Hello world Android App Build path

Tags: android, compilation

hi guys am going through the tutorial on building a hello world app from here

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I have tried everything that i could find on this forum.

- adding the libraries
- adding support libraries as a project using the following link
- https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

nothing seems to do it for me.

I am trying to run the basic tutorial app and cant seem to complie

And I cant seem to upload a screenshot as well .. :(

Comment: what error come can u show

Comment: Please post the link to the screenshot here as the comment instead.

Comment: `Logcat` is the best friend of Android developers. Check logs for error/issue description.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtq841kljxk733e/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-04%20at%205.54.06%20PM.png?dl=0

here is the screen shot

Comment: paresh log cat is not showing anything either ..

Answer (score 0):

first it is not code problem.
problem is in library had you using appcompact library if not than add it in this project and see.

or right click on **project -> Android Tools and select Add Support library** and check.

Comment: tried this as well .. doesnt seem to be working vivek

Comment: here is the screen shot